# Why arent Qt classes public functions thread safe?

Tags: qt

Example:

you cannot do item->setVisible(true); from any thread, it needs to be scheduled on the main thread.

Why isn't that handled internally? And more importantly why isn't it documented?

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with QT, normally you change/ update widget from another thread other than the main thread...

Comment: Thread safety is documented, of course. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-reentrancy.html

Comment: The reason is, I believe, that it would be extremely complicated and it would hurt performance. And it would provide just a very little benefit. It would also lead to thread overuse, especially by beginners, which is a recipe for a disaster. Btw. have you ever written a class which has all public methods thread-safe? Then you probably can imagine how difficult it would be. The code would quickly become unmaintainable and hard to extend.

Comment: @V.K, I can't seem to find any re-entrant or thread-safety documentation on ex QQuickItem... where should one look?

Comment: @V.K, it could hurt performance in some cases. Atomic locks are supported in hardware these days and have negligible overhead. I do agree that writing good thread safe code is cumbersome, however, communicating and scheduling work from one thread to the main GUI thread is not without its own potential pitfalls.

Comment: I cannot imagine how would such a code full of atomics look like. It would be a maintenance nightmare. Btw. you can do atomics only for trivial types, not for classes... If you learn to use signals and slots properly, then it is actually easy to work with multiple threads in Qt. Updating UI is very simple. Btw. all you usually need is to do some progress bar (or some other kind of showing progress) and pause/resume/abort thread functions... It really is simple to do with threads in Qt.

Comment: some would argue not having those locks is a maintenance nightmare. 

The Qt signals / slots model can be a systems nightmare, I've seen large applications shake like a christmas tree for half a second on minor GUI updates when signals caused unexpected chain events. And this was made by experienced Qt/C++ developers in billion USD companies... Qt signals can make program flows very hard to understand compare to a regular function call. I'm not saying signals/slots are bad, but they're definitely not good : )